# How to connect server by quickfix using private key

Tags: java, quickfix, fix-protocol

Im connecting to server using FIX protocol 4.4.
Previously i used username and password for authentication.

Below is my configuration file

> [DEFAULT]
>  ConnectionType=initiator
>  HeartBtInt=30
>   ReconnectInterval=30
>  ResetOnLogout=Y
>  ResetOnDisconnect=Y
>   FileStorePath=/tmp/msgs/
>  FileLogPath=/tmp/msgs/log/
>   StartTime=00:00:
>  EndTime=00:00:00
>  UseDataDictionary=N
>   SocketConnectHost=193.~.~.~
>  SocketNodelay=Y
>   PersistMessages=N
>
> [SESSION]
>  BeginString=FIX.4.4
>  SenderCompID=abcdefh
>   TargetCompID=abcdefh
>  SocketConnectPort=7000
>   SenderSubID=abcdefh
>  Password=abcdefh

Now have to connect without using SenderSubID & password, but using private key.
The keys are given in a pem file.
I am giving sample of the code below

> Bag Attributes
>       localKeyID: 12 23 34 45 56 AX SC DV FV FB 12 23 34 45 56 AX SC DV FV FB  subject=/CN=abcdefgh
>   issuer=/C=GB/ST=London/L=London/O=DB/OU=GM/CN=demo fix dev
>   -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890
>   -----END CERTIFICATE----- Bag Attributes:  subject=/C=GB/ST=London/L=London/O=DB/OU=GM/CN=demo fix dev
>   issuer=/C=GB/ST=London/L=London/O=DB/OU=GM/CN=demo fix dev
>   -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890
>   -----END CERTIFICATE----- Bag Attributes
>       localKeyID: 12 23 34 45 56 AX SC DV FV FB 12 23 34 45 56 AX SC DV FV FB  Key Attributes: 
>   -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890
>   -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

I don't know how to proceed or what to do with this PEM file
I am new to java and FIX protocol

If anyone can explain the solution with java code, that would be very helpful

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in order to connect with a counterparty with a PEM key, you have to install and config a new software.

In our production environment, we use sTunnel (https://www.stunnel.org/index.html) , a free software for tunnel and encrypt messages over a SSL layer.

Please download this sotware and read the manual for the config settings.